# Reaching files outside gulp folder

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

Is it possible to reach files (css/js/img) outside the gulp root folder. For e.g. I have in my projects a global folder where are located all global assets. The problem is that the gulp cant read those files.

Example structure:

```
global-assets
└─microsites
  └─gulpfile.js
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('htmlSSI', function() {
    gulp.src('dev/templates/*.html')
        .pipe(includer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Template file:

```
<!--#include virtual="../../../../global-assets/templates/_header.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="_main-content.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="../../../../global-assets/templates/_footer.html" -->
```

Comment: Please show us the code of your tasks.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the code. Now its there.

Answer (score 1):

My working gulp task:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    includer     = require('gulp-html-ssi'),
    es           = require('event-stream'),
    globalAssets = ['../../global-assets/templates/*.html'],
    localAssets  = ['dev/templates/*.html'];

gulp.task('htmlSSI', function() {
    return es.merge(gulp.src(globalAssets), gulp.src(localAssets))
        .pipe(includer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```